Sentry on Android: how not to collect list of packages versions?
We use last stable version of sentry android plugins and in every issue we get very long list of versions of used packages. For example, this is only small part of this list:
packages list
Is it possible to somehow configure sentry for Android not to send this list with every message? This would be useful for saving traffic and storage space))
I read documentation of sentry and information on sentry github, but but didn't find a option for my situation.

You can disable the feature as follows:
// in your app/build.gradle.kts file
sentry {
  includeDependenciesReport.set(true)
}

here's the relevant documentation page: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/android/configuration/gradle/#configure

Thank you very much, it what I needed! I have no idea how I missed this :-]
